# Test endpoints compliance against openapi contract in Spring Boot Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, openapi

I am looking for a nice way to write tests to make sure that endpoints in Spring Boot Rest (ver. 2.1.9) application follows the contract in the OpenAPI contract.

In the project I moved recently there is the following workflow: architects write contract openapi.yml and developers have to implement endpoint to compliance the contract. Unfortunately a lot of differences happen and this test has to catch such a situation and it is not possible to change this.

I was thinking about a solution to generate openapi.yml from current endpoints and compare it with my OpenAPI contract that it should follow. I wonder if there is some out of the box solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking about the solution to generate openapi.yml from current ednpoints and compares it somehow but wonder if there is some out of the box solution.

In a general case, even the generated spec may not match the actual app behavior because some things can't be expressed with Open API. However, it still could be helpful as a starting point.

Open API provides a way to [specify examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/), that could be used to verify the contract. But the actual schemas might be a better source of expectations.

I want to note two tools that can generate and execute test cases based only on the input Open API spec:

1. [Schemathesis](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis) uses both examples and schemas and doesn't require configuration by default. It utilizes property-based testing and verifies properties defined in the tested schema - response codes, schemas, and headers. It supports Open API 2 & 3.
2. [Dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd) focuses more on examples and provides several [automatic expectations](https://dredd.org/en/latest/how-it-works.html#automatic-expectations). It supports only Open API 2, and the third version is [experimental](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-elements.js/blob/master/packages/openapi3-parser/STATUS.md).

Both provide a CLI and could be extended with various hooks to fit the desired workflow.

I'd suggest passing the contracts (as a spec you mentioned) to Schemathesis and it will verify if all schemas and examples are handled correctly by your app.

Answer (score 0):

[Specmatic](https://specmatic.in/) [Contract as Test](https://specmatic.in/#contract-as-test) generates tests based on your OpenAPI specification. Here is a [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5Agz-mvYIU&t=39s).

Disclosure: I am Co-founder and CTO at Specmatic

If you want an exhaustive list of tools in this space here is a page that you may want to look at [https://openapi.tools](https://openapi.tools/#testing).